# What is the correct capitalization of "gmail"?

Tags: gmail

What is the correct capitalization of the webapp "gmail"?  In plain text on the Google site it is referred to as `Gmail`, but the logo suggests `GMail`.  I have also seen on this site `gmail` or even `gMail`.

Is there a canonical capitalization?

[image: Screenshot of Gmail capitalization on mail.google.com]

Comment: in Germany they call it "Google Mail" (because of trademark issues) and this solves the problem ;-)

Comment: used to be like that in the UK too, but they resolved it: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=159001

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally at Google we have flip flopped between GMail and Gmail, but we've settled on the latter. Gmail it is.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [help documentation](http://mail.google.com/support/?ctx=gmail&hl=en&labs=1), it's "Gmail":

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It is newspaper editors and journalists that sweat the most over details like this, so I think this is off topic.

That said, a quick search of Google News shows most (all?) news outlets writing "Gmail"

The logo has a capital M solely because they wanted to fit an envelope icon into the logo.

Comment: Of course, if you pay attention to my local news station, I use an Iphone. \*shudder\*

Answer (score 2):

Since it was even called Google mail for a long time in a few places, I'd say Gmail!